# Приведение матрицы к треугольному виду методом Гаусса с выбором главного элемента по строке

Tags: матрицы

Надо найти определитель матрицы. Сначала привести ее к треугольному виду методом Гаусса с выбором главного элемента по строке.
Вот исходная матрица:

```
-1 2 -5
4 -1 3
3 0 -6
```

После приведения к треугольному виду она становится такой:

```
-6 3 0
0 5.5 -1
0 0 1.3636
```

Но их определители не совпадают(по знаку). Что я упускаю?

```
-1 2 -5      3 0 -6     -6 0 3       6   0   3        -6   3  0      -6  3    0
4 -1 3   ->  4 -1 3  ->  3 -1 4  ->  0   -1  11/2 ->  0  11/2 -1  ->  0 11/2 -1
3 0 -6       -1 2 -5    -5 2 -1      0   2  -7/2      0 -7/2  2       0 0 15/11
```

Answer (score 2):

Перестановка строк (или столбцов) матрицы меняет знак её определителя, так что нужно подсчитывать перестановки, и при нечетном их количестве поменять знак определителя в конце